# STM32F0, ST-link v2, OpenOCD 0.9.0: open failed

Tags: stm32, openocd

I'm using [Launchpad's](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/about.html) gcc-arm-none-eabi 4.9-2015q2 to compile for an STM32F0, and now I'd like to debug using arm-none-eabi-gdb from that collection. My ST-Link v2 is part of a Nucleo F411RE board, with external hardware (the STM32F0 target) attached. Flashing the F0 works fine, so I conclude that my SWD connections are good.

Now I want to start [OpenOCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_Cortex-M_development_tools#Debugging_tools), but it fails:

```
$ openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2015-07-26-16:02)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Error: open failed
in procedure 'init'
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

What might be wrong here?

I also couldn't establish a connection using st-util, which reported timeouts and in the end always crashed with a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Comment: it seems that is a problem with stlink usb connection. first check USB cable, try another USB port, or look into dmesg if you are in linux, for windows maybe it is problem that you don't have drivers from ST.

Comment: This question came up as a result on a search for an identical problem with the STM32F4-DISCO board. It seems like at some point, ST switched to using the STLink V2-1 (see @sprhawk's answer) on that board. Noting this for anyone who finds themselves here for that reason.

Comment: Setting to software reset worked for me. See link : http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread418#threadId5193

Comment: Had a similar problem: wanted to debug stm32f429 chip with stm32f0discovery and it didn't work with `-f board/stm32f0discovery.cfg` no matter if I used `-f interface/stlink-{v2,v2-1}.cfg` but finally just using `-f board/stm32f429discovery.cfg` and `-f interface/stlink-v2.cfg` worked. So maybe it depends on the target (here an stm32f429x chip)?

Answer (score 16):

Nucleo F411RE embedded a stlink v2-1 not stlink v2

so change the script file like this:

```
source [find interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg]

transport select hla_swd

source [find target/stm32f4x.cfg]

reset_config srst_only
```

Answer (score 4):

The file `stlink-v2.cfg` might be ok. You probably should use `stlink-v2-1.cfg` file (inside that file is `hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x3748`).

Comment: This has helped me (STM32F4).

Comment: I'm using an STM32L031 and this resolved the connection issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I also got `Error: open failed` but all the configuration was OK. Then I did `dmesg | grep usb` to see why it cannot connect via USB (on Ubuntu). The dmesg told me that there are power issues and perhaps the cable is faulty. As I had used the same cable earlier the same day and some LEDs still flashed on the board, I first ignored the message. But then I finally decided to try, bought another cable and lo and behold! It was a faulty cable - with the new one everything works. So, not always a software problem after all.

Though if you do `lsusb` (or use device manager in Windows) and the board is nicely listed, it will probably not be a cable issue. If it is missing, it might be.

Comment: I've spent one evening trying to fix that. Turns out usb cable was the problem. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix.  The VID/PID pair in stlink-v2.cfg was wrong. They had this:

> hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x3748

but it should be this:

> hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x374**B**

letter "B", not the digit "8".

Comment: As @sprhawk pointed out in their answer, there is another profile with an ST Link v2-1 that has the proper 0x374B PID.

Answer (score 0):

1.in eclipse ide-->project-->inc --> {project_name} debug.cfg  ->source [find interface/stlink.cfg]

check your interface debugger whether stlink.cfg or stlink-v2.cfg or stlink-v2-1.cfg
and change  [find interface/stlink.cfg]

{or}TRY

2.C:\Ac6\SystemWorkbench\plugins\fr.ac6.mcu.debug_2.5.0.201904120827\resources\openocd\st_scripts\interface\stlink.cfg(or stlink-v2.cfg or stlink-v2-1.cfg)

add hla_vid_pid 0

Answer (score 0):

**ID error related to OPENOCD failed:**

**fix-1:**

Modify Stm32f1x.cfg file to set _CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477 from set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477
**before: set _CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477**

**after   : set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477**

**fix-2(if not resolved):**

modify stlink.cfg ,stlink-v2.cfg and stlink-v2-1.cfg file,add extra command like below

**hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x374B 0**

**Any Power reset issue during dubug run:**

debug configuration -> debugger tab -> show generation option --> changed setting to **software reset**